# Is GPU not updated every frame as CPU is?

Tags: graphics, gpu, directx-11, compute-shader

I'm learning about graphics programming and am trying to practice by building a particle system. As every particle should have a lifetime, I'm tracking the lifetime in a compute shader.

The problem is that the particle's life ends too fast, I set the life time to 10 but it lasts for only about 3 seconds.

This is a function in my compute shader, it's called in the main shader as long as ParticleBuffer[id].active is true. The particleDeltaTime is a constant buffer variable in which delta time is calculated in the cpu and sent before the compute shader is bounded.

```
void UpdateParticle(int id)
{
    
    float t = ParticleBuffer[id].time / ParticleBuffer[id].lifeTime;
    if (t >= 1.0f)
        ParticleBuffer[id].active = 0;
    else
    {
        ParticleBuffer[id].time += particleDeltaTime;
        float3 acceleration = float3(0, -particleGravityRate, 0);
            
        ParticleBuffer[id].position += ParticleBuffer[id].velocity *
            particleDeltaTime + 0.5 * acceleration * particleDeltaTime * particleDeltaTime;
            
        ParticleBuffer[id].rotation += particleRotationSpeed * particleDeltaTime;
        ParticleBuffer[id].velocity += acceleration * particleDeltaTime;
    }
}
```

This is my Compute shader, OnExecute is called every frame.

```
void ComputeShader::OnExecute()
{
    Binds();
    GetDevice()->BindComputeShader(mCS.Get());
    GetDevice()->Dispatch(mGroupX, mGroupY, mGroupZ);
    clear();
}
```

I'm not sure on what I don't know, if there is a better way to explain or solve my problem, any pointers will be thankful.

Thanks for taking your time.

Comment: have you tried timing your fps, take timestamps after `Present()`. This could be faster  [`SyncInterval=0`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-idxgiswapchain-present) and slower than you monitors refresh rate

Comment: The answer to "Is GPU not updated every frame as CPU is?" question is no, or doesn't mean much. There are very different hardware chip and are physically separated. Moving data from CPU to GPU is relatively costly. It's difficult to understand what you're trying to do. Maybe with some reproducing code https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See [Understanding Game Time Revisited](https://walbourn.github.io/understanding-game-time-revisited/)

Answer (score 0):

To fix your issue, try changing your position equation to:

```
ParticleBuffer[id].position += ParticleBuffer[id].velocity *
        particleDeltaTime;
```

You don't need to add 0.5 * acceleration * deltaTime^2. I think you are getting slightly confused with kinematic equations here. You are already applying acceleration in the last line of code, eg:

```
 ParticleBuffer[id].velocity += acceleration * particleDeltaTime;
```

Acceleration is defined in meters per second squared, because it simply means that velocity increases in some amount of "meters per second", per second. You don't square your time values.

As for the other part of your question, the frequency of CPU vs GPU updates is generally controlled by you. (If you're not limited by vsync or performance) How often are you submitting commands? If your application is single threaded and you are rendering/calling present once per loop, then your CPU and GPU should be in sync.

An easy way to test this could be to avoid using delta time, and just rely on vsync and use 1/refreshRate as your delta time value.

Also, an extra tip, update velocity before position. This is known as semi-implicit euler, instead of explicit euler, and is more stable, as it does not gain energy over time.

Taking things a tiny step further, with anything physics-based (Eg using velocity, acceleration, mass) you shouldn't use a variable delta time, as this leads to unstable and non-deterministic results. Instead, you should always step forward with a fixed timestep (Eg 1/50 = 0.02 milliseconds per step, or 50fps) and run your physics simulation as many times as needed to update it to the correct game time.

The bottom two articles here might be helpful, they describe semi-implicit euler (Bottom) and fixed timesteps. (Second bottom) https://gafferongames.com/categories/game-physics/